# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, referenceerror

I'm trying to put together a Wordpress site with a JQuery slider plugin, but the plugin doesn't display on the page and I always get the above error message.

Despite trying several different fixes suggested in other's posts I still can't seem to fix the above error, including putting the script tag in the 'header.php' file. Any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

**Relevant code in 'footer.php' file**

```
    <!--Load JQuery-->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>


</body> 
</html>
```

**The Website:**`http://www.advanceprojects.com.au/`

Comment: what's wrong with putting the library in the header?

Comment: The error is because jQuery is not loaded before the slider attempts to use jQuery and so the error is thrown.  To fix it, ensure jQuery is loaded before the slider.  Putting it in the footer means you either would have to include the slider after this in the footer or later as well, or move the jQuery include earlier, like in the header.

Answer (score 6):

Scripts always run in a sequential order.

So basically you are trying to use jQuery even before the jQuery library is loaded.

Your script is dependent on Nivo which in turn depends on jQuery library.

Either move the script to the line after the library is loaded, or move the library declaration to the head.

Also make sure you enclose the script inside `DOM Ready` handler.

So the order in which you should be loading these are

```
-- jQuery 
  -- Nivo Slider
  -- your script that uses the above 2 libraries.
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

Add the line

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

This error happened because jquery is not included, and should be included before loading any other script.
Here is an example:

firstplugin.php

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Plugintrial
Description:  plugin to test jquery
Version:      1
Author:       Dismi Paul
*/
function childtheme_custom_login() {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

wp_enqueue_script('my-custom-script', plugins_url('/test.js', __FILE__));
?>

    <h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>

<p id="intro">My name is Donald.</p>
<p>I live in Duckburg.<?php echo plugins_url('/test.js', __FILE__); ?></p>

    <?php
}

add_action('login_head', 'childtheme_custom_login');
```

test.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
  jQuery("#intro").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
console.log("it works");
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I am seeing this same issue with WooCommerce and the Siteground Optimizer when Defer Render Blocking Javascript is on, there is a WC script that references jQuery first (seems to be a date picker script  setting defaults) - not a custom script I've added, and not a plugin as far as I can tell.  My scripts use jQuery and come later, and are fine, but this references it in the head tag prior to jQuery being available... Also this only happens while NOT logged in.  If you're logged in, it works fine, log out, broken.

**Turning off the Defer Javascript option in SG Optimizer seems to fix the issue.**

Comment: Wow, I spent 5 hours trying to find the solution and tried many methods that seemed to work, but didn't. I was in the exactly same situation as you and your highlighted line just did the trick lol. Thanks!

Comment: THANK YOU for finding this link to SG Optimizer!!! i was trying to enqueue a script & added the script_loader_tag filter to add the async attribute which kept breaking my site. either not adding that filter or turning off the SG setting works! much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

See The Link How to add css and Js File

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Probably Before JQuery,Your Js File Is Loaded.

So add js file after Jquery file is Loaded

Example

```
wp_enqueue_script("yourjs","yourjspath",array('jquery'), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

In a recent version of Wordpress this can be caused by core performance improvements:

Try placing this in your wp.config file:

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#wpns_slider').nivoSlider({effect:'random',slices:2,});
});
```

instead of

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
     jQuery('#wpns_slider').nivoSlider({effect:'random',slices:2,});
});
```

`$(window).load(function() {... })` is explicitly binding to the window's load event, your code has already fired before `jQuery` library is loaded. You have to use **`DOM Ready`** handler.